# Writting two DB context for two DBs in the same project with EF core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a need for creating a project where I will writing two DBcontexts for two different Databases, Is it possible to do this using EF Core 3.1. if yes can somebody please comment on the link for the material which I can go through.

Answer (score 0):

well to answer my own question, it is possible to do so and it's similar to the way we do it in EF 6.
a simple example is at.
https://medium.com/@hidayatarg/working-with-multiple-databases-in-entity-framework-core-code-first-b34f5dbff377